# Installing Laravel on a subdirectory. The whole app must be public

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

So, my client won't pay for a cloud server, instead he wants to use his own webserver where he hosts other projects. I tried to explain him, but no success. I can't even have a good old cPanel instance.

Let's say *public_html* is the root dir, meaning I can't upload Laravel in the parent directory.

How can I securely deploy the app?

I was thinking something like this:

- **public_html**

  - **app**: basically contains the whole project except the public folder

    - **.htaccess**: blocking traffic
  - **public**: the laravel public folder
  - **.htaccess**: pointing traffic to public/index.php

Do you guys know if this is doable? Any advice in terms of security?

Comment: if they have a webserver why can't they just setup a new virtual host for this project so it doesn't have to be in a subfolder off of another site?

Comment: Not sure about the security but try to upload the whole project folder to public_html and points the domain to `public_html -> 'my app folder' -> public`